# Is it a problem to compare a string to an INT column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, string, query-optimization, where-clause

if I have an int column of `id`, is it bad for performance to have a query written like

```
SELECT * FROM products where id = '1'?
```

Or does MySQL handle this the same as

```
SELECT * FROM products where id = 1
```

Comment: Performancewise, the difference is going to be negligible. But they are capable of returning different result.

Comment: MySQL uses the leading digits of a text field when converting to `int`, so [`123 = '123foo'` is true](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/182207).

Comment: There's an implicit assumption in your question I think that `id` is an `int` type. On general principles of [Postel's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle), be strict in what you provide, so provide a comparison with the type that you are comparing to.

Answer (score 2):

In general: don't do this. Compare values against a literal of the correct datatype, so you don't have to worry about what is going on under the hood. If you have an integer column, then:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = 1
```

In this specific situation: when asked to compare a number to a string, MySQL converts the string to a number. So there would be (almost) no performance penalty if you were to use:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = '1'
```

The literal string is converted once, and then checked against every value in the column.

On the other hand, consider a string column, say `str`, and a predicate like:

```
WHERE str = 1
```

Now it goes the other way around. MySQL needs to convert all string values in `str` to numbers before they can be compared. The expression becomes inefficient -  it cannot take advantage of an index (it is *non-SARGable*). If there are many rows, the performance impact may be important.

So, back to the initial recommendation: know your datatypes; use the proper literal when comparing.

Comment: Why would MySQL not turn the 1 to '1' in your "WHERE str = 1 example?

Comment: @Ben: MySQL follows a set of predefined rules when asked to compare values of different datatypes. And the rule says that a string and an integer should be compared as numbers. See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html. If you don't want to worry about this, use the proper datatype from the start, as recommended in the answer...

Comment: Thanks, just curious

Comment: Also mysql will produce `Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value` warning if `str` is not a number

Answer (score 0):

If performance is your concern, numbers are smaller than text in this example--1 is faster than "1".

HOWEVER... if you're looking for performance never start with SELECT *

Answer (score 0):

The cases:

```
WHERE int_col = 2      -- Good
WHERE int_col = "2"    -- Good; the "2" is turned into INT at start of query
WHERE int_col = "2foo" -- Probably not what you wanted

WHERE char_col = 2     -- Slow; `char_col` is turned into INT for each row
WHERE char_col = "2"   -- Good
```